# Is it possible to "triangulate" the location of a termite colony in a horizontal space using light sources as attractive bases?

Tags: entomology, behaviour

So we have termites and I noticed that one of the can lights in our subfloor (the 1.5 foot vertical space between our first and 2nd floor) was a lift off point for many swarms. I put some tape over the can light and was able to catch the swarmers each time they did it. The termite guy wouldn't touch the area (useless good for nothing) because it was an "electrical" area and out of risk or harm I had to remove the can light first before he can investigate the area. Left before we figured out how to open it (I wish I was good at this kind of stuff... took less than 30 seconds once you understood the trick to remove it). In any case, the termite specialist says since the colony has spread in between the floors he can only offer tenting since other methods will be ineffective but he also knows we are an attached home and that means the only way we can do anything is if all neighbors agree to the tenting of which we are all unable to do at the moment due to a long story I won't get into here. In any case, I've been endoscoping the heck out of the area... plenty of other things I found in there except termites, I was wondering is it possible for me to "triangulate" the nest source?

It seems like that specific can light has a direct line of sight to the colony because all the swarmers go straight for it and none other. I was wondering would it be possible for me to place three different light sources in the space and see which ones will trap the most termites and maybe use that information to zero in on the nest location. Anyways, a bit of a wild idea but maybe its possible. I already know that triangulation and trilateration are useful if you are at your own location so that would mean the nest needs to be known but maybe there is something I am missing where I could locate the nest using light sources and traps and wait until swarm season. Anyways just a thought..

Comment: Perhaps better in the Biology Stack.

Comment: Please explain. Why would you think that? I feel like Biology would have something more about how to identify species or the anatomy of animals - not how to locate a nest/colony for extermination. Pest control seems very much a DIY topic.

Comment: Because termite behavior under changing lights conditions is not Home Improvement…

Comment: Termite behavior is better asked about on Biology.

Comment: Interesting question and reasoning tho. Try the three lights thing and post an answer to your own question.

Comment: My approach with termites is to spray every possible place with poison . We get the type that build tunnels to the ground so I have a pretty good idea where they are . I have had them in the garage twice as they are common here .  Apologies for the political incorrectness of insecticide.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Wish I had the same problem, unfortunately they are in the area that doesn't touch the ground - we believe they are drywood termites and yours sound like subterranean termites. Subterranean termites create those tunnels and come from the ground so that is a great tell!